# How to pipe with strings?

Tags: c++, pipe

I am new to pipes in C++ and hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I am attempting to have a string be read into a pipe and then access then write that string into a text file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    std::string atary = "first line\nsecond line\nthird line\n";
    int main_to_sub[2];
    int sub_to_main[2];
    pipe(main_to_sub);
    pipe(sub_to_main);
    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        // sub-process
        dup2(main_to_sub[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(sub_to_main[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(sub_to_main[0]);
        close(sub_to_main[1]);
        close(main_to_sub[0]);
        close(main_to_sub[1]);
        char* argv[] = {"wc", "-l", nullptr};
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
    }

    // main process
    write(main_to_sub[1], atary.c_str(), atary.size() + 1);
    int status;
    waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
    close(sub_to_main[1]);
    close(main_to_sub[0]);
    close(main_to_sub[1]);
    char buffer[100];
    long count = read(sub_to_main[0], buffer, 100);
    buffer[count] = '\0';
    std::cout << buffer;
    close(sub_to_main[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

This is code provided from [here](https://gitlab.com/rdi-eg/docs/wikis/Fork,-Exec-and-Pipe-for-4-Year-Olds-and-Up).  Rather than printing out the number of lines, how could I access the actual string.

Comment: Can you clarify which C++ compiler you seemingly used to compile the above. gcc rightfully complains about the shown code being ill-formed no matter which standard compliance level is selected, C++11, C++14, C++17, or even C++03 (for different reasons). The shown code appears to be quite broken in this, and several other ways, too.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I used g++ and got a warning.

Comment: Ah, at C++11 it's only a warning, not an error. Now, what was your intent for calling `waitpid()` with the WNOHANG option? In this case, it does absolutely nothing. And what exactly do you mean by "the actual string"? You have your string there: it's "3".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am using code provided from the link above, I did not write this code but rather am using it as a way better understand pipes with strings in general. As to the WNOHANG option I am not sure of the purpose I am sorry.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik What I mean by the actual string is "first line\nsecond line\nthird line\n"

Comment: Well, you already have it. You declared it in the first line of `main()`. You want to "access" it? The variable is "atary".

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am sorry I thought the example provided above would provided a more general idea of the task I am trying to accomplish, what I am really using it for is have a process writes in a text file a code fragment that it has reconstructed, via a child then end its execution. Its parent process, upon detecting that its child process has terminated, reads that file, and sends its content to the root process via a pipe. The root process collects and concatenate together all the pieces of the reconstructed file, and writes the reconstituted file.

Comment: The reason you’re getting the number of lines is that you’re calling `wc -l`!  Call the right program, get the right output.

Comment: @DavisHerring could you point me in direction of a reference for this material?

Comment: @MattC: How can I provide a reference for whatever other command it is that you want to run?

Comment: @DavisHerring You are right, I did not understand entirely that "program" were just classic command line arguments and not something else when I a made that previous comment, either way I figured out cat will just write the string into the buffer, I thank you for your help.

Comment: @MattC: There is of course no point in invoking `cat` just to get back the text you write to it.

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes I agree no value in this context, but in other programs it could be useful.